# Display the different salary figures earned by faculty members arranged in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Display the different salary figures earned by faculty members arranged in descending order, without any duplication. Do not display any other information.

I am new in database.
Can any one help me to solve this problem I can't understand how to do? I have attach the picture of faculty table.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Arranged in descending order by what? Without duplication of what? What information should be displayed, just the salary?

Comment: Also, please show us what you have tried.

Comment: can you help me to do this ? Display all faculty members with an annual salary exceeding 80,000 as "Tenured Faculty.  but FName and LName both show in 1 Tenured Faculty column

Comment: You should ask that as a new question as it is completely separate from this question (which is also marked as answered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you want to have a list of unique salary values in descending order. This is how you can achieve it:

```
SELECT Salary FROM faculty
group by Salary
order by Salary desc
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT distinct(Salary) FROM faculty
order by Salary desc
```

This will give you all the salaries in descending order. If two people earn 10k, you will only see 10k once.

```
SELECT Salary FROM faculty
group by FacultyID, Salary
order by Salary desc
```

This will give you all the salaries grouped by faculty id in descending order with no duplicates within a faculty.

Comment: thank you very much . its working for me.

Comment: can you help me to do this ?
Display all faculty members with an annual salary exceeding 80,000 as "Tenured Faculty".

Comment: solution was working kindly vote the question to get out of minus.